# Getting rid of ValueErrors when taking log of probabilities

Tags: python, probability, logarithm

I want to find the maximum probable path and I tried to associate log probabilities to get rid of underflow errors when multiplying sequence of steps.

While calculating the maximum probable path, I iteratively retain only the best paths and remove the others from the start to end (Consider the image I drawn here). After the first step (I dont have to remove any since, there is only one path from initial state to first state) I am retaining only the best possible path to that state and that state will have a probability up to that state.

In the step 3 (I have not shown here) this score will be multiplied with the other state transition probabilities and algorithm will choose the best path to each state at third step. However, as you could see since the score associated with the node(marked with *) is -3.0 upon which will throw an ValueError when trying to calculate it's log value. Any idea to get rid of this?

[image]

P.S I have already done the implementation and do not wanted to show it since it is very large and hard to explain. The error just lies on the following line where best_incoming_weight = -3.0 here

```
    probability = math.log2(best_incoming_weight) + math.log2(current_incoming_weights)
```

Comment: Please review [on topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) from the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). "Show me how to solve this coding problem?" is off-topic for Stack Overflow. You have to make an honest attempt at the solution, and then ask a specific question about your implementation. Stack Overflow is not intended to replace existing tutorials or documentation, and is not a way to have research, design or coding work done for you.

Comment: @Steve I have already done the implementation using python. Since it is hard to show code as it is very long, i tried to draw and explain the reason I am getting that error. Thanks for making it asked for close and downvoting. People like you are really helpful!

Comment: "However, as you could see since the score associated with the node(marked with \*) is -3.0" I don't understand. What is the logic that tells you the result should be -3.0? I can't read your handwriting very well, but it looks like you have "log 0.3 + log 0.4 = -3.0" (base 2 logarithm apparently; I get -3.05 or so, but whatever). *If you are already adding the results of logarithms* (to avoid multiplications), *then you don't need to take the logarithm again*.

Comment: To the extent that I can make any sense out of the question at all, it seems pretty clear that you have a math question, not a programming question. Please try https://math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: @hEShaN - I reversed my downvote because even though this problem doesn't belong here, you telling me that you do have code and just don't think it's worth showing changed my opinion.  I think I would have come at this differently if you'd said that initiallly, although maybe I should have gotten that from what you were asking.  I like the discussion here...that maybe you did get some help.  Anyway, you now have two upvotes!

Comment: @Steve Thanks for understanding. Since the logic was connected and the code I wrote has not much comments I did not want to share it here as I actually did not know a better way of explaining from top to bottom. The link show the code that will expire in 12 hours https://codeshare.io/5R0Y04

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You computed the logarithm of the probability. It must be negative or zero because log of any number between zero and one is non-positive. To convert the obtained result to traditional probability, you need to compute `2**probability` where `probability` is as above.

Comment: Thanks! I think I understand what I am doing wrong here! Basically, before using it back in the next step, I should convert it back to the probability. :)